# scheduledTimer in swift 3

Tags: timer, swift3

Is this the correct way to fire off a repeating timer in swift 3?

- Note that this code has to run on iOS 8 as well.
- Does the userInfo need to be a dictionary?
- Can this code be improved?

```

```
class ABContactManager : NSObject {
    func waitForContactsToLoad(_ onSuccess: @escaping (() -> ())) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(
           timeInterval: 0.5,
           target: self,
           selector: #selector(ABContactManager.timerFired(timer:)),
           userInfo: ["callback" : onSuccess],
           repeats: true)
    }
    func timerFired(timer: Timer) {
        logInfo("keep polling contacts")
        if let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? [String : Any] {
            if let onSuccess = userInfo["callback"] as? (() -> ()) {
                if self.loadingStatus == .loaded {
                    logInfo("stop polling -- loaded contacts issue callback")
                    onSuccess()
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, then what is your issue exactly?

Comment: The code compiles fine, but I am in the process of converting a large body of code to swift 3.  I won't get to try this out till later.  I am concerned about whether I need to hold a reference to the timer object in the class as well as the correct syntax for the #selector call.  Under the covers this code is calling the objective-c version of NSTimer I think. Which probably means that UserInfo got to be a dictionary.  I was hoping to have a canonical example of the use of this API that I can use throughout my code.

Comment: Actually the callback closure is redundant and not needed.

Comment: the calling function needs to know whether the contactsAreLoaded.  Hence the callback closure.

Comment: You do not need to hold a reference to a Timer once its scheduled because the Runloop retains a strong reference to the Timer; check the documentation.  Also userInfo is of type Any? which in Swift 3 is the mapping of Objective C's id.